# List of all databases contained in a docker container

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, docker, containers

I have multiple databases in multiple containers.
It is starting to get confusing to know which containers hold which database.

So my question is very simple, is there a way to get the list of all the databases contained in a docker container?

docker ps -a 
gives the list of all containers created, but how do I know which container contains a specific database?

There must be a command line that would do just that, give me the list of all my mssql databases contained in each containers,
as of now I have to guess which container hold which database in order to access the database.

I'm hosting the docker containers on a mac.

Comment: Docker is just a tool to host containers; it's not specifically designed to host SQL Server it's just something it can do. My personal suggestion would be to check the databases that are on each container (yourself) and then document which container is hosting which. Then, as well, make updating the documentation part of your company's procedures; then you always know which containers are hosting which databases, or what container you need to access for a specific database.

Comment: Microsoft themselves tell you to use docker if you want to run their server on mac.

Comment: Yes, bceause Mac itself cannot host SQL Server; hence you use Docker to create a container (and environment) that SQL Server can run in. Docker itself is not created, or maintained by Microsoft; it is open source 3rd party software. If you are experience with other container software, you can use that instead (for example, I use `lxc`in my home environment). Docker is just the one that Microsoft provide documentation on how to setup the environment. Docker can do much more than *just* host a SQL Server instance, like I said, and it doesn't have SQL Server commands itself.

Comment: Like I said, documentation is key here. Take the time to inspect all of containers/Virtual environments and document what they are doing; then you solve the problem and you have something to refer to in the future.

Comment: yes, that is a solution but it sucks. As in order to document it, I will have to try to connect to each database from each container and document which ones won't say connection error.

Comment: Why not inspect `sys.databases`? There's certainly no need to try to connect to ever database. Just find out what databases on the server, don't try and connect to every database you know exists. You could also very easily miss one then.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer to my question.Now I need to figure out how to use it.

Comment: `SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4;` will return all user databases. (1-4 being `master`, `tempdb`, `model` and `msdb` respectively.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker has no knowledge of what's running inside it, so you have to ask SQL Server directly.

`select [name] from sys.databases where database_id > 4` will list all user databases on a given instance (or, in your case, container).

Connect to each instance/container and run that query. If you use Central Management Server, this is much easier as you can execute the same query against a number of servers at once.

If you don't have a CMS, you can do it by passing the list of instances to the `dbatools` PowerShell module function `Invoke-DbaQuery` and get similar results.

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -serverinstance InstanceOne,InstanceTwo -query "select [name],@@SERVERNAME from sys.databases where database_id > 4;";
```

Another option (again using `dbatools`) is to use `Get-DbaDatabase`. This will return more data about each database than the name.

```
Get-DbaDatabase -serverinstance InstanceOne,InstanceTwo
```

Comment: Or just use the multi-server query SSMS feature, with a registered server group containing each database container.

Comment: Considering the OP is using mac, they may well not have access to either Powershell or SSMS.

Comment: I see the important MacOS detail was in a comment rather than part of the question. I'll add it.

Comment: @Larnu PowerShell and `dbatools` are both available for macOS

Comment: thanks for this I was able to find the exact answer on Microsoft website now that I knew what to look for, the showed when checking if an imported .bak database was properly done; unrelated problem but same solution of course it was at the bottom of the page, Verify the restored database (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-2017) then I had this issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/315), now everything is good. welcome to c#/.net on Mac OSX